# Anaconda error: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, peewee

`pip install peewee` fails with Anaconda on Windows 10.

- OS: Windows 10
- Python: Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
- Cython: 0.27.3

#### error

`playhouse\_sqlite_ext.c(531): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'D:\\MyIDE\\VS2015\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

**But when I used official Python without Anaconda, it installed successfully**.So what can I do for installing peewee successfully with Python in Anaconda?

Comment: Is there a reason you used `pip` instead of `conda` to install `peewee` for Anaconda?

Comment: My guess is that with python.org Python, either (a) `pip` finds a wheel that matches exactly your build, (b) the package can tell you don't have `sqlite3` C headers and skips building the sqlite connector, or (c) the package can find and use the `sqlite3` C headers; with Anaconda, `pip` is instead trying to build from source using the same C headers used to build the stdlib `sqlite3` module but those headers don't exist; with `conda` you'll just get the package out of the conda repo and everything will be fine.

Comment: @abarnert with `conda install peewee`, it produced PackagesNotFoundError.With `anaconda search -t conda peewee`, I don't find right package.

Comment: Ah, do you not know about conda-forge, for community packages? See [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/peewee) for the Peewee package, which also shows how to install packages off conda-forge.

Comment: @abarnert You saved me a lot of time, the only regrettable thing is that the version of peewee is a little old, just 2.10.2.

Comment: I don't actually know that much about the conda-forge process. I assume there's either a way to ping the uploader to ask them to package a new version, or a way to trigger a new pull/build/test semi-automatically, but I don't know what it is. Hopefully someone else comes along who does.

Comment: @abarnert Unfortunately, I have to use the latest version of peewee, and I want to know why no sqlite3.h?(Hasn't it installed with Python?)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on Win7-X86 with VisualStudio 2017 Community and Anaconda 3 installed.
Problem is that sqlite3.h not found during compiling with C/C++ compiler.
File is available in Anaconda installation in Library\Include.
During linking you will not find sqlite3.lib in Library\include.
You can add proper CL and LINK environment variables to solve problems.

Below presented pyx.bat to start python.exe with additional environment variables to fix problem. Don't forget fix PYTHONPATH for your location either inside BAT or you need it in system level environment.
Use it from command line as of:

pyx -m pip install -U peewee

I have this pyx.bat on the PATH, while no Python on the path

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: variable PYTHONHOME may be required for the Python.exe.
if "%PYTHONHOME%" == "" (
REM set PYTHONHOME=c:\Progs\Python
REM set PYTHONHOME=c:\Progs\Anaconda3x86
set PYTHONHOME=d:\InstSoft\Python\Anaconda3x86
REM set PYTHONHOME=d:\InstSoft\Python\Python361x86bin
)

set PY_EXE=Python
set PY_RUN=%PYTHONHOME%\%PY_EXE%.exe
if NOT exist "%PY_RUN%" (
  echo Missing: %PY_RUN%
  echo Check environment variable:
  echo PYTHONHOME=%PYTHONHOME%
  goto :eof
)

:: below required to run pip or conda, problems with py.bat:
:: conda may not find pythonw.exe since py.bat don't need PATH
:: covering PYTHONHOME, add it here:
set PATH=%PYTHONHOME%;%PATH%

:: conda or pip install may use VisualStudio and some headers/libs not found
:: while available at %PYTHONHOME% inside Library\include and Library\lib
:: (may happen when pip is used with Anaconda)
set CL=/I%PYTHONHOME%\Library\Include
set LINK=/LIBPATH:%PYTHONHOME%\Library\lib

echo Run: %PY_RUN%
echo Arg: %*
"%PY_RUN%" %*

:: eof
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 3.1.x, you should be able to specify an environment variable to skip compilation of sqlite-extensions. See docs: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/installation.html#skip-compilation-of-sqlite-extensions

```
$ NO_SQLITE=1 python setup.py build
```

Comment: Just use `conda install -c conda-forge peewee`, the version of [peewee](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/peewee) is v3.1.5 now, it's enough to use for me.